# Verify a specific and unique group of values in a group

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have a MySQL table with the following structure:

[image]

I  want a query that would receive a group of `uid`s (or a single `uid`) and then check for their existence in a closed group under a specific mid. If they exist, the query should return the `mid` under which they exist. For example in the table above:

```
('chuks.obima', 'crackhead') should return '2
('vweetah','crackhead') should return '1'
('vweetah','crackhead','chuks.obima') should return 3
('crackhead') should return an empty result
```

Comment: What should be the output for `('favour','crackhead','charisma')` then?

Comment: @yes123 Edited it -maybe a little better, but hard to capture the OP's need (if I even understood it)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: i didn't edit it because I had no clue about it

Comment: Who cares there's a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT mid
FROM your_table
WHERE uid in ('favour','crackhead','charisma')
GROUP BY mid
HAVING COUNT(*)=3
```

**EDIT:** based on your second example, this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT mid
FROM your_table
WHERE uid in ('vweetah', 'crackhead')
GROUP BY mid
HAVING
  COUNT(distinct uid)=
  (select count(*)
   from (select 'vweetah' union select 'crackhead') s)
```

or you can just substitute last subquery with the number of elements you are looking for, e.g. `HAVING COUNT(distinct uid) = 2`

**EDIT2**: now i understand exactly what you are looking for. This should give you the correct results:

```
SELECT your_table.mid, s.tot_count, count(distinct uid)
FROM
  your_table inner join
  (select mid, seq, count(distinct uid) tot_count from your_table group by mid, seq) s
  on your_table.mid = s.mid and your_table.seq=s.seq
WHERE your_table.uid in ('crackhead')
GROUP BY your_table.mid
HAVING COUNT(distinct uid)=s.tot_count AND COUNT(distinct uid)=1
```

where the last count is equal to the number of elements you are looking for. This could be simplified like this:

```
SELECT your_table.mid
FROM your_table
GROUP BY your_table.mid
HAVING
  count(distinct uid)=
  count(distinct case when your_table.uid in ('vweetah','crackhead','chuks.obima') then your_table.uid end)
  and count(distinct uid)=3
```

If the group is to considered closed if all uid are under the same `seq`, you also have to modify group by with: `group by your_table.mid, your_table.seq` and your select with `SELECT distinct your_table.mid`

Comment: You solution doesnt work for data in the second table image. if i check for crackhead and vweetah unless i change the count to 6.

Comment: Try with `COUNT(DISTINCT uid) = 3`.

Comment: @BillKarwin don't undersyand you. Why on't you create a new answer and if it works i'll award you the bounty.

Comment: @fthiella ur answer doesn't work if i try a single uid like 'crackead'. it just returns all group where crackhead is a member.

Answer (score 2):

To verify that it is a closed group, you can get the aggregate `COUNT()` of the total members of that `mid` group and compare it to the number of people in your list. If they are equal, it is closed.

The following would return a `1` if all 3 are in the group, and the total number of people in the group is also 3.

```
SELECT
  (((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE `uid` IN ('favour','crackhead','charisma') AND `mid` = 2) 
  =
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE `mid` = 2)) 
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE `mid` = 2) = 3) AS group_is_closed
```

Wrap it in a subquery to avoid counting the `mid` twice.

```
SELECT
  /* 3 is the number of uid you are looking for */
  (mid_count = 3 AND mid_count = member_count) AS group_is_closed
FROM (
  SELECT
   /* Find how many of your uids are in the `mid` */
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE `uid` IN ('favour','crackhead','charisma') AND `mid` = 2) AS member_count,
   /* Find the total number of uids in the `mid` */
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE `mid` = 2) AS mid_count
) subq
```

#### SQLFiddle demos (*aka wow, it actually works*):

- [Positive result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a058/1) (Only the 3 selected are in the `mid`, returns 1)
- [Negative result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae4ec/1) (A user not among the 3 is also in the `mid`, returns 0)
- [Negative result 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e142b/1) (One of the 3 users is *not* in the `mid`, returns 0)

Comment: the mid under which they appear should be the result of the query. Pls read my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT mid
FROM your_table
WHERE uid in ('favour','crackhead','charisma')
GROUP BY mid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uid) = 3
```